# Sails.js disable cookie set for OPTIONS requests

Tags: angular, cookies, cors, sails.js

I am developing an app which uses Sailsjs as backend and Angular 4 on different server as backend. Due to this I mus thave enable CORS and every HTTP request coming from angular app is prepended by OPTIONS request which is I believe added by browser. Problem is that Sailsjs creates cookies for this OPTIONS request but this cookie is not saved in browser.

Therefore my redis server is being overwhelmed by a lot of cookies made by OPTIONS request. What I want to achieve is to disable OPTIONS request cookies. I have tried it by following route config:

```
'OPTIONS /*': {
    cors: {
        credentials: false
    }
}
```

my global CORS config looks like this:

```
allRoutes: true,
origin: 'http://127.0.0.1:4200',
credentials: true,
methods: 'GET,POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD'
headers: 'content-type, authorization, timeout'
securityLevel: 1
```

but this is not working and server always responds with cookie set for OPTIONS requests. Any idea on how to set this up correctly?

**UPDATE**
Studying the documentation of Sailsjs I have come up with another solution, which is also not working.
I have added this code to session settings:

```
routesDisabled: ['OPTIONS /*']
```

but this have disabled session for all requests ignoring that I have specifially wanted only OPTIONS requests.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I solved it the problem is bug in sails version `0.12.14` which is at this time latest stable version.

File `lib/hooks/http/get-configured-http-middleware-fns.js` contains at line 88 this statement

`if(!isMethodExactMatch && !isMethodImplicitMatch && disabledRouteInfo.method === '*'){`

but it should be

`if(!isMethodExactMatch && !isMethodImplicitMatch && disabledRouteInfo.method !== '*'){`

after making this change I've got it working.

Comment: Good find. You should report the bug to the sails team.

Comment: I was already thinking about it but they are in process of development of sails version 1.0 and a lot is changed inside it so I will wait for stable version, check if bug is still there and if so I will report it

Answer (score 0):

For those on older versions without the `routesDisabled` option, you can put a shim in front of the built-in sails session middleware.

```
customSession: function customSession(req, res, next) {
  const noSessionRoutes = [
    '/'
  ];
  //if this is an OPTIONS request, browsers won't send a cookie, so don't create a new session
  //for API routes, we also don't want to create a session and/or respond with a cookie 
  if (req.method.toUpperCase() === 'OPTIONS' || noSessionRoutes.includes(req.url)) {
    req.session = {};
    return next();
  }
  //this will fall back to the built-in sails session configured in session.js
  else {
    sails.config.http.middleware.session(req, res, next);
  }
}
```

Then `middleware.order` looks something like this:

```
order: [
  'cookieParser',
  'customSession',
  ...]
```